# Run multiple ajax when page load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, servlets

I write three ajax function like below:

```
function showClass()
{
    ...
    var url="getObjectProperty?"
    ....
}
function showDtPro()
{
    ...
    var url="getDataTypeProperty?"
    ....
}
function showObjPro()
{
  xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
  if (xmlHttp==null)
  {
     alert ("Your Browser Don't support AJAX");
     return;
  }
  var url="getObjectProperty?";
  url=url+"sid="+Math.random();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=loadObjPro;
  xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

except the "url" is different, the other things are the same.This ajax is used to get the data from three different servlets and update the tag in html.
One of the servlets is below:

```
 //This function is used to get the data from an jena model and response the data to the client.
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    //
    ArrayList<String> ObjectPropertyNames=new ArrayList<String>();
    //Define the jenaOwlModel 
    JenaOWLModel jenaOwlModel;
    try {
        OntModel ontmodel=MyModelFactory.getJenaModel().getOntModel();

        ExtendedIterator ObjectProperties = ontmodel.listObjectProperties();
        while(ObjectProperties.hasNext()){
            ObjectProperty property = (ObjectProperty) ObjectProperties.next();
            if(property.getLocalName()!=null)
            {
                ObjectPropertyNames.add(property.getLocalName());
            }
        }   
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }         
            response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
            String AllObjectProperties="";
        for(int i=0;i<ObjectPropertyNames.size();i++)
        {                    AllObjectProperties=AllObjectProperties+ObjectPropertyNames.get(i)+"#";
        }
        System.out.print(AllObjectProperties);
        out.print(AllObjectProperties);  
        out.flush();  
        out.close();
}
```

The other servlet is almost the same with this one.Now I want to load the data from the three servlets when the page is loaded.So I write in the windows.onload function like below:

```
window.onload=function()
{
   showClass();
   showObjPro();
   showDtPro();
 }
```

But it doesn't run as expect.Sometimes,only the last function`showDtPro();`fetch the data.The other two function don't fetch the data. Sometimes, the tag should be updated by `showClass()` and `showObjPro()` appear the data get from `showDtPro()`.

```
 <div id="class">
   <h4>Class</h4>
     <ul id="rdfclass" type="dclass"></ul> 
</div> 
<div id="obj">
     <h4>Object Property</h4>
     <ul id="rdfobjpro" type="dobjpro"></ul>
  </div>  
<div id="dt">
     <h4>Datatype Property</h4>
     <ul id="rdfdtpro" type="dtpro"></ul>  
</div>
```

the html tag is above. Correspondingly, the three functions are used to update the three`<ul>`tag.
I am a beginner to web develop. I hope to get your help! Thank you !

Comment: That's a lot of repeated JavaScript you got there...

Comment: Purpose of jQuery tag???

Comment: None as far as I can see. Removed the tag.

Comment: you are right, I should wrapper the repeated code as function.And I will delete the unnecessary code in this question

Answer (score 0):

That is because ajax is asynchronous. You'll have to implement some callbacks etc..

The execution is not synchronous in case of ajax.

Comment: Yes,but could you help to explain why it always show the data fetch from the last function? And why sometimes the tag should be updated by showClass() and showObjPro() appear the data get from showDtPro().Does this three function are related?